# How to append an extra 'Zero' after decimal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Hye,
Iam new to javascript working with one textbox validation for decimal numbers . Example format should be 66,00 .but if user type 66,0 and dont type two zero after comma then after leaving text box it should automatically append to it .so that it would be correct format of it . How can i get this .How can i append ?? here is my code snippet.

```
 function check2(sender){
           var error = false;
           var regex = '^[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9]$';
           var v = $(sender).val();
           var index = v.indexOf(',');
           var characterToTest = v.charAt(index + 1);
           var nextCharAfterComma = v.charAt(index + 2);

            if (characterToTest == '0') { 

              //here need to add 
            }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to do more than just add a zero if the value ends with `,0` -- you probably want to add two zeros if no comma apears, and to truncate down to two if more than two digits are placed after the comma, correct?

Comment: ya bit but for example user typed 99,0 and forgot to type one zero then it shud automatically place one zero like this 99,00 . then it wud be correct format in my case.

Comment: Thought so.  Then definitely go with OptimusCrime's solution of using `.toFixed(2)`

Comment: thanks but i dont want to round the digits

Comment: What do you want if the value in the box is `87,289` then?  Do you want to leave it at `87,289` or truncate to `87,28`?

Comment: sorry u were correct , for example if user type 99,875 then it convert to 99,88 but just two digits after comma

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `.toFixed(2)`

Read this article: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/formatnumber.shtml

|EDIT| This will also fix the issue if a user types in too many decimals. Better to do it this way, rather than having a if to check each digit after the comma.

Answer (score 2):

.toFixed() converts a number to string and if you try to convert it to a float like 10.00
then it is impossible.

Example-

1. 10.toFixed(2)       // "10.00" string
2. parseFloat("10.00") // 10
3. Number("10.00")     // 10